# Running a node.js/express app on a remote server for others to access?

Tags: node.js, linux, express, ssh, server

I've never done anything like this so forgive me if this is a dumb question or should be posted somewhere else. I have a super simple Hello World app (for testing purposes) that I'm trying to run from a remote linux (red hat 7.6) server that i use putty to connect to, and then be able to access that page from any machine (on the same network). the linux server is CLI only so it's not a virtual machine type thing where you go to a web page on the server and view the page.

when I run the app from my own laptop and go to `localhost:3000` or `(my-IP-address):3000`, it works just fine, but I'm kind of confused on how to get this to work when it's run from a completely separate machine. it runs without error on the server so I don't think it's anything with the code...

this is my code:

```
var express = require("express"),
    app = express(),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    bodyParser = require("body-parser"),
    methodOverride = require("method-override"),
    http = require("http");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.send("Hello World!");
  });


  app.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0", function() {
    console.log('Server running');
  });
```

In the server I added this for the firewall (also something I haven't worked with before)

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```

but it still doesn't seem to connect. I feel like I'm missing some key step somewhere but can't find anything else online that's worked so far

Answer (score 0):

Try  to telnet to the port in that machine `telnet yourIP 3000`and see if that port is open so if it's not then you'll have to make sure that it's open In aws you generally change the rules I believe.(I wouldn't suggest this generally because you'll make it public)

Comment: I tried it and it says connection timed out, which I assume means it's not open. it's on a corporate network so I dont think im allowed to open the port. is there another way to go about this if i can't open the port?

Comment: You can expose the port from your local machine by using something like ngrok https://ngrok.com/product, but i dont think its the right solution

Comment: @Emily is there any other open ports in remote server? Or is server using any reverse proxy like nginx? You have to open the port that specified your app or use a reverse proxy in a different open port.

Comment: @NisanCoskun there might be a different port open, i'll look into using nginx. thanks for the tip!